# Hide pause/play button on vimeo iframe on hover

Tags: javascript, iframe, vimeo, froogaloop

I am using a Vimeo iframe on a website. I hide all the controls with the Vimeo Froogaloop API. But I can't hide the pause and play button that appear on hover. Somebody please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('iframe.vimeo-player').each(function(){
      Froogaloop(this).addEvent('ready', ready);
  });
  function ready(playerID){
      console.log(playerID + ' is ready');

      // Add event listerns
      // http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#events
      Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('play', play(playerID));
      Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('seek', seek);


      // Fire an API method
      // http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#methods
      Froogaloop(playerID).api('play');
      Froogaloop(playerID).api('setVolume', 0);

  }
  function play(playerID){
      console.log(playerID + ' is playing');
  }
  function seek(data, playerID) {
      console.log(playerID + ' is seeking');
      console.log(data);
  }
```

});

Comment: May you provide any code or a fiddle?

Comment: I don't know if you're still working on this problem, but I just came to a new conclusion and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>According to a [forum post](https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:43217) from 2 years ago, this is impossible. The post suggests upgrading to pro and using a third-party player.</strike>

The only other option would be to switch to a different video platform to get the features you want.

**Edit:**

It looks like it's actually possible. I just saw an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hkq3c6Lm/) (linked to from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35406279/5764553)) which has the buttons in question removed.

The key appears to be setting the parameter `background=1` in the URL of the `iframe`. Oddly enough, this functionality does not appear on [Vimeo's developer site](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding).

Comment: Thanks Andrew but this facility is only available for the pro users.i have checked it.