# Play-button with Froogaloop on mobile

Tags: html, vimeo, froogaloop

I've created a play and pause button using Froogaloop, to control my Vimeo-video - and they work fine on desktop, but they do not work on mobile. I use Autoplay with the video, but since that is not working on mobile I need these buttons to work.
This video is a background, so the built in play-button is not an option.

Can anyone help me?

```
Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hkq3c6Lm/
```

Comment: You may need to [contact Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/help/contact) (or post on their [forum](https://vimeo.com/forums/help)). Since iPhones pipe Vimeo video into their own video player app (instead of showing it in the browser), I'm not sure if a video background is even possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vimeo player JS API is not working in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967342/vimeo-player-js-api-is-not-working-in-ios)